# Loop for inserting range of values in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to run following sql query to populate table, but am unable to run it... any ideas?

```
BEGIN
FOR n in 21500..21600 LOOP

   if mod(n,2)=0
   then    
       dbms_output.put_line(n||'even');
   else
      insert into port_mapping(APP,VERSION,BUSINESS,CRITICAL,SUPPORTED,TYPE,PORT,NOTE)
      values("SDS","1","No","Yes","Yes","Server",n,"NA");
   end if;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

I am getting the error

> PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here ORA-06550: line 8, column
>   7: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values are in double-quotes, which makes them (column) identifiers as far as Oracle is concerned. You need single quotes:

```
...
  values('SDS','1','No','Yes','Yes','Server',n,'NA');
...
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d69dc/1).

You don't need PL/SQL for this - you could use a simpler insert-into with a select-connect-by - but I'm not sure if you're doing this as an exercise.

```
insert into port_mapping (APP,VERSION,BUSINESS,CRITICAL,SUPPORTED,TYPE,
    PORT,NOTE)
select 'SDS','1','No','Yes','Yes','Server',
    21500 + (level * 2) - 1,'NA'
from dual
connect by level < 51;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f4f30/1).